# python3: Create a dictionary from two inequal lists with two or more None key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary from two inequal lists that number of keys is two times lower than the value:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

`>>> dict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', None: 'c', None: 'd', None: 'e'}`

Manually creating this dictionary is possible, but I need to create it in for loop.

Comment: You cannot have multiple `None`s as dictionary keys, since the keys must be distinct. Do you maybe want your `a`/`b`/`c` to be keys and `1`/`2`/`None` to be values?

Comment: Manually creating this dictionary is possible, but I need to create it in for loop.

Comment: It is not possible because Python will leave only one value for key `None`. Try printing out the dictionary after you've created it manually.

Answer (score 1):

It's *kind of* possible, just not how you might expect.

**Given**

```
import itertools as it
import collections as ct


a = [1, 2]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

**Code**

*Dict of Lists*

```
d = {}
for x, y in it.zip_longest(a, b):
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)

d
# {1: ['a'], 2: ['b'], None: ['c', 'd', 'e']}
```

```
dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
for x, y in it.zip_longest(a, b):
    dd[x].append(y)

dd
# defaultdict(list, {1: ['a'], 2: ['b'], None: ['c', 'd', 'e']})
```

*Reversed Dict*

```
dict(it.zip_longest(b, a))
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': None, 'd': None, 'e': None}
```

---

**Details**

As mentioned, keys of Python dicts are unique.  Your options are a dict of lists, or a reversed dict.

However, if you insisted on an `a:b` key-value pair with `None` keys, you could make tuples of `None` with some unique value, e.g. list indices:

```
{x if x is not None else (x, i): y for i, (x, y) in enumerate(it.zip_longest(a, b))}    
# {1: 'a', 2: 'b', (None, 2): 'c', (None, 3): 'd', (None, 4): 'e'}
```

In your case, I would suggest a reversed dict.

Comment: It's great, but I want another output that seems not to be possible.

Comment: There is a way, but it's not a good is idea to fight how dicts naturally work.  Often there is  a better solution. Why do you need this particular output? Does it have to be a dict? What is the bigger problem you are trying to solve?